# To get all nodes and path from edge to root using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get all nodes information with paths from edge to root node.Using one of the edge property.

This is the three layer node structure.

[image]

```
MATCH (g:GrandChild{name:"C"})<-[:childToGrandChild]-(c:Child)<-[p:Parent*0..]-(c:Child) RETURN c,g,p
```

This will return only B,C nodes with relationship like this

[image]

**cypher used**

```
CREATE (p: Parent{name : '1'} ) RETURN p

MATCH (p:Parent) WHERE p.name = '1' CREATE (c: Child{name : '2'} )<-[:parentToChild]-(p) RETURN p


MATCH (c:Child) WHERE c.name = '3' CREATE (g: GrandChild {name : '2'} )<-[:childToGrandChild]-(c) RETURN c
```

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `parentTochild` relationship which will be like,

```
MATCH (g:GrandChild{name:"C"})<-[:childToGrandChild]-(c:Child)<-[parentToChild*0..]-(p:Parent)
RETURN c,g,p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
MATCH (g:GrandChild{name:"C"})<-[:childToGrandChild]-(c:Child)
MATCH (c)<-[p:Parent*0..]-(c2:Child) 
RETURN c,c2,g,p
```

Comment: Thank you for response. This is giving child and grandchild node. Not Parent